# My laptop won't let me enter my password

Tags: windows, laptop-repair

This started a couple of days ago when my laptop's built-in keyboard suddenly stopped working for no apparent reason. So I tried the usual "turn it off and turn it back on again" approach, and now I have real problems. My laptop has one of those hard drive passwords, but as soon as I try to enter it, the laptop shuts down. I have no idea what to do, so any help would be great...

Comment: What is the make & model number ? OS ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever spilled a liquid on your keyboard? Because it sounds like maybe the key connections are being bridged and causing a button such as `Esc` or similar to be pressed when you press another key.But this isn't always the case. This could just be an issue of old age and worn connections or traces.

Have you tried using a USB keyboard? Try seeing if this works (just to eliminate any possible issues with it being the laptop). Unfortunately a USB keyboard *may be* your only option in a situation like this unless you are willing to either pay for someone to replace your keyboard, or do it yourself.